# How to install jupyter notebook on mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to run a `jupyter` notebook on my mac where I have installed `jupyter3.6` and `jupyterlab`.

```
python3.6 -m pip install jupyterlab
```

If I run the notebook

```
python3.6 -m notebook
```

The broswer open the right page but I get an error

```
KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
WARNING:root:kernel f2bf7ea6-6f33-49a6-ad7c-3a2c60c41b6d restarted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 582, in initialize
    self.init_kernel()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 452, in init_kernel
    user_ns=self.user_ns,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 91, in __init__
    appnope.nope()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appnope/_nope.py", line 90, in nope
    "Because Reasons"
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appnope/_nope.py", line 60, in beginActivityWithOptions
    NSProcessInfo = C('NSProcessInfo')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appnope/_nope.py", line 38, in C
    assert ret is not None, "Couldn't find Class %s" % classname
AssertionError: Couldn't find Class NSProcessInfo
```

Comment: I'd say install anaconda and that will install jupyter notebook as well. Anaconda also offers virtual envt. which will help in maintaining different versions of library

Comment: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9410

Comment: You could try [this](https://github.com/minrk/appnope/issues/12#issuecomment-741625144)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is discussed in https://github.com/minrk/appnope/issues/12. Here are the potential solutions:

1. one can [disable app nap](https://github.com/minrk/appnope/issues/12#issuecomment-741625144).

```
# ~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py
c.Kernel._darwin_app_nap = False
```

2. One can [use python 3.8+](https://github.com/minrk/appnope/issues/12#issuecomment-742180903). This issue [only seems to happen in python version <3.8](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9410#issuecomment-736805982).

Comment: I can't find `ipython_kernel_config.py`

Comment: You can create it. See https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html.

Comment: I dit but I still get the same error. I added the line `c.Kernel._darwin_app_nap = False` using `nano /Users/myname/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`

Comment: That filepath is different from the one in my answer. Can you please refer to the ipython configuration link I commented above?

Comment: I did `jupyter notebook --generate-config` and I get `Writing default config to: /Users/myname/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`